# Different screens for different roles or conditional rendering of widget based on roles in one screen?

Tags: flutter, design-patterns

I developing my first "complex" application in flutter + firebase where there are 4 different roles in the application. Guest user, Plus user, Pro user and Admin user. Different user groups have access to different functions in the application (different widget shown etc).

I see two possible alternatives how this can be implemented.

1: Different screens/views for different user groups. Home_Guest, Home_Plus, Home_Pro and Home_Admin and load screen depending on user roll (There are over 10 different screens/view in the application, so it will be different 40+ screens/view If I go this route).

2: One screens/views where different widgets are loaded depending on the user group. Home: if Guest load A, if Plus load A+B, if Pro load A+B+C and if Admin load A+B+C+D etc...

Pros/Cons:

1:  More code and some repetition of code

2:  Less code, no repetition of code but more complex logic

I know that there are probably different opinions from different developers but i have tried to find an article, book etc on the subject but find nothing. **What I'm asking is if there is one (or more) "best practice" or "well known" patterns that I can follow? And any book, article, etc. that describes this pattern?**

Comment: My problem can be answered with facts!  Is there is one (or more) "best practice" or "well known" design patterns to solv my problem ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these screens have a lot of UI elements in common i would go with the 2nd option
you could create Map<UserGroup,Widget> that maps the user groups to widgets which you can easily call in your UI  but also be aware if you are planning to release this as a serious application

You have to implement firebase security rules to actually make this secure, simple UI logic can easily be reverse engineered

Comment: Good suggestion with a map, it solves a lot of the complexity! I have a good understanding of the Backend, everything is locked with security roller or behind cloud functions with custom claims etc. Hopefully the app is unique and good enough to be launched!

Comment: @CarlFågel can you update the answer how can you implement practically?